# Why same Python Torrent program being executed several times prints different lists?

Tags: python, torrent

**Short problem description:**

```
python Download.py
[('131.111.185.76', 6969), ('131.111.5.154', 51413), ('199.180.253.176', 45384)]
python Download.py
[('131.111.185.76', 6969), ('131.111.5.154', 51413), ('199.180.253.176', 45384)]
python Download.py
[('131.111.185.76', 6969), ('131.111.5.154', 51413), ('199.180.253.176', 45384)]
python Download.py
[('131.111.185.76', 6969), ('199.180.253.176', 45384), ('131.111.5.154', 51413)]
```

Running the same deterministic program, on the fourth time the output was different. Why?

**More detailed explanation**

I am writing my own torrent client (university homework assignment). I got up to the point of extracting the peers list (i.e.: list of tuple(IpAddress, port)).
For debugging purposes I wanted to print the list.
After running program several times I got the list elements printed in different order.

Here is a short snippet of code:

```
import bencode;

.... # some code ommited

# 2) Sending GET request to the tracker
trackersResponse = requests.get(fileMetadata['announce'], params = parameters);

# 3) Decoding trackers response
decodedTrackersResponse = bencode.bdecode(trackersResponse.content) ['peers'];
peersList = PeersListDecoder.decodePeersList(decodedTrackersResponse);

print peersList; # This line prints weird results
```

My own code is completely deterministic, and I believe that library procedures that I use are also deterministic. The only reason I can figure out why different lists get printed is because the **tracker** returns different results. Could that be the case?

Comment: I think its too much to expect all peers to be in same state till u finish ur deterministic code :)

Comment: Why do you believe the tracker's response is always deterministic? I would test this assumption first. Use Wireshark or just print the tracker's response directly.

Comment: I do think that tracker's response is not deterministic. What I struggle understanding is why it would change the order of peers after 4 calls done in several seconds.